# Reusing InMemoryDatabase across unit tests

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core-mvc, in-memory-database

I have ASP.NET MVC Core application that I am writing Unit tests for. I am using InMemoryDatabase and it is working great. I want to initialize database once for the test run. So, I have a static class:

```
public static class DbInitialize {
    private static MyDbContext _db;

    public static MyDbContext Initialize() {
        if (_db != null) {
            return _db;
        }
        DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyDbContext> optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyDbContext>();
        optionsBuilder.UseInMemoryDatabase();
        _db = new MyDbContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
       ....... (populating mock data) .............
       _db.SaveChanges();
       return _db;
    }
}
```

Works great for a single test class (say, `HomeControllerTests`) and all its specific tests. However, if I have another test class (`CustomerControllerTests`) and I call `DbInitialize.Initialize()` - I see that `_db` is null, but the database was not destroyed - I get Key error during `SaveChanges()`. Is there a better way to initialize the database *only once*, and get a "connection string" (for lack of better word) if it is already up and running?

Comment: What happens if you recreate the `DbContext` everytime with your options (without the data)?

Comment: @GabrielGM - I am not sure I understand your question. If I create DbContext without the data at all - nothing bad will happen, except I don't have the data, and unit tests obviously fail.

Comment: You're saying that your `_db` is null, even though it 'exists' in memory. When that happens, can you recreate the `_db`. I mean, Create and seed the first time. After that, just create.

Comment: the essence of the question is to how do I know when is the first time, and when is after that... I found the answer in xUnit documentation; about to post it

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, xUnit has an answer for exactly this situation - [Collection Fixture](http://xunit.github.io/docs/shared-context.html#collection-fixture). I followed instructions there, and it worked out. Hopefully, it will help somebody else as well :)